# Why Hashtable's equals method test the situation that value is null or not

Tags: java, hashtable

I am reading the Hashtable's code, and I learned that both Hashtable's key and value can not be null, but its equals method test the situation that value is null or not.

```
public synchronized boolean equals(Object o) {
if (o == this)
    return true;
if (!(o instanceof Map))
    return false;
Map<K,V> t = (Map<K,V>) o;
if (t.size() != size())
    return false;

    try {
        Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            K key = e.getKey();
            V value = e.getValue();
            if (value == null) { // Can Hashtable's value be null?
                if (!(t.get(key)==null && t.containsKey(key))) 
                    return false;
            } else {
                if (!value.equals(t.get(key)))
                    return false;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassCastException unused)   {
        return false;
    } catch (NullPointerException unused) {
        return false;
    }

return true;
}
```

Comment: It could be for future purpose, down the line they can extend the features. But as per good programming guidelines, you always need to check NPE

Comment: Don't expect the code of the standard libraries to be perfect - it can simply be that the person who wrote it didn't think about it.

Comment: Why read the code of a class whose use has been discouraged for nearly ten _years_?

Comment: I'm sorry but I want to learn the difference between Hashtable and HashMap.

Comment: All operations on a `Hashtable` are `synchronized` and it doesn't accept null keys or values. That is all there is to it. The Javadoc says it all already ;) But DO NOT use a `Hashtable` in code you write. It is obsolete.

Comment: @fge there is nothing wrong in going through the source code. And though it has been discouraged for nearly ten years, it is still used in many APIs. For ex I am still using  InitialContext(Hashtable<?,?> environment) function(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html).

Comment: @AniketThakur which is no reason to use it in code you write... There is code in the JDK which uses double check locking, does it mean it is recommended that you use it? ;)

Comment: No absolutely not. I am just saying there is nothing wrong in going through the source code. It's only effect is better understanding. Don't mind... my response was based on OP saying sorry which he need not. After all curiosity is mother of all inventions ;)

Comment: You would have to ask the author, who is probably either retired or in pre-sales by now, 17 years or so later. Anything you will get here will just be more or less uninformed guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of a pattern that is followed throughout to handle the NPE. Consider a simple class

```
public class HelloWorld {
    String data;
}
```

If you generate hashCode() and equals() you will see this general pattern followed. As in this case

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    HelloWorld that = (HelloWorld) o;

    if (data != null ? !data.equals(that.data) : that.data != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return data != null ? data.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

As you can see we always check for null. It is not mandatory but a good programming practice. I understand it makes no sense in the case of Hashtable's but as I mentioned earlier developers must have added this check to maintain a uniform pattern.

**Update** : As Tim has suggested `Since Hashtable is subclassable, it is possible for a subclass to try to support null keys or values`. So it is safe to do a null check.

Comment: Since Hashtable is subclassable, it is possible for a subclass to try to support null keys or values (or accidentally provide them) - so it is sane to check for that case.

Comment: Good point @TimBoudreau. I agree. Updating my answer to incorporate your point.